# How not a trigger a action if same radio button selected again?

Tags: javascript

I have bunch of radio button and i trigger a action when the radio button is selected. 
I don't want to trigger the action if user selects the already selected radio button again.

Thanks
Om

Comment: What have you tried? Since you should be triggering off the "change" event, I'm surprised it's firing if the value hasn't changed.

Comment: Please, as always, provide you code right now... we don't make homework for you

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an `onclick` event? Use an `onchange` event instead.

Comment: Thats great. You are right i was using onclick. i changed to onchange and it worked thanks

Comment: Probably you should accept the answer if it solves what you asked :D